# How to explode a dict column into a new dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [[20, 30, [{"ab":"1", "we":"2", "as":"3"}, {"ab":"4", "we":"5", "as":"6"}],"String"]],
            columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I want to explode the 'C' column into a new dataframe.
It is formatted as dict but its type is an object.
Tried converting it into dict using ast.literal_eval but while doing that on the full dataframe I got an EOF error.

Desired output of the new dataframe:

```
ab    we     as
1     2      3
4     5      6
```

Comment: kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: @sammywemmy - I have added the desired output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `apply` with `pd.Series`

```
df.C.apply(pd.Series)
```

Output

```
  ab we as
0  1  2  3
```

If the column type is `object`, use this

```
df.C.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(literal_eval(x)))
```

If you have invalid `dict` objects

```
def explode_dict(row):
    try:
        return pd.Series(literal_eval(row))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error Converting', row)
        return np.nan

df.C.apply(explode_dict)
```

If the column is a list of dict, use,

```
df.C.explode().apply(explode_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but it does not explode the dict to columns, instead leaving the dict in one column. Problem is that the column format is object

Comment: Added for object type column @gtomer

Comment: Thanks! However, see in the above question - I have tried literal_eval - but it produced errors. Probably there are some dicts which are not formatted correctly

Comment: If they are not formatted correctly, then your dataset is not clean/good. Try to fix it at the source. Or, you could just ignore that data.

Comment: I have added my question. Apparently the column has a list of dicts

Comment: Please don't change the question frequently. @gtomer Check answer,